# Automatic Git commit when Junit test success with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I have a Java project using gradle.
As the title says, I would like to know if their is a way to commit automatically on a git repo when the test with Junit is a success using gradle. It will be even better if it's in background at each code modification (like the command `$ gradle -t test`).
Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this for some kata or community practice ? And what would be the automated commit message ?

Comment: You may consider some CI server for this task like TeamCity. It integrates with IntelliJ IDEA and has the [pre-tested commit feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit).

Comment: The commit message could be the actual date .

Answer (score 1):

I have my concerns about this approach but you can create a gradle afterTest hook like (completely untested):

```
test {
    afterTest { desc, success -> 
        if(success) makeCommit()
    }
}
```

Then, just implement the commit logic using the JGit api: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit